# online bank bank transfer

Tags: scams, online-banking

I have meet a boyfriend online and ask me to make an online bank account because theres a so-called bank manager will transfer the huge amount. He helps me make a personal online bank account and transfer the so-called money on it. Now they ask me to transfer it to my personal bank account that i have personally but when i am about to transfer from the online account to my personal account they ask me to pay the Cot Code to transfer the money successfully with the amount of 1270 USD.
I open my account in Trustbond company that the so-called bank manager from a Cooperative bank help me do it. Can anyone here clear my mind about this I am being curious if this is legit or not.Your answers and advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Online romantic relationship plus any form of money transfer equals fraud in progress.

Answer (score 5):

You are being scammed. You did the right thing by asking! (Note: we are just people you do not know on the internet, but you will get legit information.) There is no money and no boyfriend.

Also, don’t try to figure out all the steps of the scam. Part of the scam is to misdirect you into thinking “This is not a scam because they sent me some money.” Don’t talk to the “boyfriend.” Don’t talk to his “manager.” Don’t talk to his “sister.” They will say something designed to make you doubt that it is a scam. Back in the old days, “con game” was short for “confidence game.”
Even if you are thinking “They can’t get anything from me, I’m broke anyway,” they can use your account to launder stolen money. Then you get a visit from nice men and ladies in suits with badges.

If you really want to know, look at many of the questions on this site with the scam tag. Including the duplicate in the comments.

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but great job on recognizing something was not quite right and asking for help!